# jQuery UI dialog goes offscreen when using position fixed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jQuery UI to display a dialog and I want it to always stay at the same position regardless of the scroll state. So I just added the css code

```
.ui-dialog {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Now if you drag the dialog to the bottom, it is possible to move it offscreen so that it is completely gone. Anyone knows how to prevent that?
See this fiddle for a demonstration: https://jsfiddle.net/d0pgfwk7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally fixed my problem. The solution was not to use the draggable setting of the dialog but to use the widget itself. So my code now looks like this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog(
    {
      draggable: false,
      dialogClass: 'my-dialog'
    }
});
$('.my-dialog').draggable({
    containment: 'window'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can get you are saying the jquery dialog box is draggable. 
If this is the case it is pretty simple fix 
just use

```
 draggable: false
```

See the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/d0pgfwk7/

EDIT : Please look at fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/LZ9SR/

For more details refer this link https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8741

Comment: Well I should have said that the dialog should be draggable. ;)

Comment: @MatthewDarton please look into the new fiddle

Comment: Hmm...by downgrading my jquery ui to 1.9. it actually works. But this is not an option for me since other functions in my project depend on the current jquery ui version.